# How can I fake having a high-DPI monitor on Windows?

Tags: windows-10, display

For testing purposes, I need a Windows 10 computer with a high-DPI monitor.  I don't happen to have one, though.  Is there some way to convince Windows that my 20-inch 96-DPI 1680x1050 monitor is actually a 10-inch 200-DPI 1680x1050 monitor?

Comment: What kind of testing?

Comment: I've got users reporting that a program I develop is drawing things wrong.  One of the bug reports includes some screenshots that are strong evidence for it being DPI-related.

Comment: Well, at the very basic level you could change the Scaling settings on your screen. This would effectively check a lower-than-normal DPI level, which would at least give some evidence.